# Remap alt+arrow in Safari / OSX

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to use the keyboard shortcut Alt+LeftArrow to go back a page in Safari. I tried adding this shortcut in System Preferences / Keyboard Shortcuts, but it had no effect. What can I do instead?

I am able to use System Preferences to assign other keyboard shortcuts to Safari's Back command. I am also able to assign Alt+LeftArrow to other menu commands in other apps. But Safari obstinately insists on interpreting Alt+LeftArrow as "scroll left a page", and it ignores my attempts to override that behaviour.

Comment: You realize that both `Ctrl-Left` and `Command-Left` are already assigned to "Back", making that shortcut kind of redundant, even if possible?

Comment: I have a Fingerworks touchpad which recognizes a left-swipe gesture and turns it into the "Alt+LeftArrow" key combination. That's why I want this keyboard shortcut.

Comment: You could try to use KeyRemap4Macbook (works for all Macs despite the name) to remap Option and Control or Option and Command in Safari only.

Comment: BTW, it the keyboard shortcut *does* work when editing the URL. I thought I was going insane until I figured out I still had the custom shortcut assigned...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be possible to use `Opt-Left` for any menu item in Safari. While the keyboard shortcut is assigned to the menu item, pressing it doesn't trigger the menu item.

You could try to use a key remapping software like [KeyRemap4Macbook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) (works on all Macs, despite its name) and switch `Control` (or `Command`) and `Option` in Safari only.

Be aware that this will probably impact other key combinations as well, e.g. `Cmd-Opt-I` for the Web Inspector, or `Opt-(Shift-)Letter` which is used for international or other characters, like e.g.:

> œ∑´®†¥¨^øπ“‘åß∂ƒ©˙∆˚¬…æ«`Ω≈ç√∫~µ≥¡€#¢∞§¶•ªº–≠Œ„‰ÂÊÁËÈØ∏”ÅÍÎÏÌÓÔÒÚÆ»ÛÙÇ◊ıˆ˜¯˘¿

If you don't necessarily need it to be `Option`, you can always press `Ctrl-Left` or `Command-Left`, which both trigger the *Back* action.

---

You can also use e.g. [Butler](http://manytricks.com/butler/) and its *Keystrokes* item to only remap `Opt-Left` to `Cmd-Left` in Safari only. All other key combinations will continue to work as before. The only difference will be in text fields, where `Opt-Left` will behave like `Cmd-Left` (obviously).

> [image]
>   [image]